# Tabbar changes tab title on list scroll

Tags: flutter, listview, tabbar

I'm trying to add Tabbar with multi-tabs with one view to all tabs(ListView), what I want to do exactly is when the user scrolls the list and reach to the group2 I need the selected Tab changes to group2 either when the user tab on Tabbar tab group3 I want the list automatically scrolls to the group3

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60523262/flutterscroll-changes-tabs